# Render Markdown In Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, markdown, vue-props

I did a small blog in Vue JS that renders posts with title and description. I would like to be able to use markdown in the description so I used [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked).

It works fine when I hard code a text in a data, but trying to pass my description which itself comes from a props, it doesn't work.
See below my code I commented what doesn't work and let an example with hard coded data.
Any idea how to fix this? With thanks!

```
<template>
  <div class="til-list">
    <div v-for="til in tils" :key="til">
      <div class="til">
        <h3>{{ til.title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ til.description }}</p>
        <div v-html="markdownToHtml"></div>
        <!-- <div v-html="markdownToHtml(til.description)"></div> -->
        <span v-for="tag in til.tags" :key="tag"> #{{ tag }} </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import marked from "marked";

export default {
  props: ["tils"],
  // computed: {
  //   markdownToHtml(description) {
  //     return marked(this.description);
  //   },
  // },
  data() {
    return {
      markdown: "# Hello World",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    markdownToHtml() {
      return marked(this.markdown);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `methods` instead `computed` property:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  //props: ["tils"],
  data() {
    return {
      tils: [{title: 'title 1', description: '<b>text</b>'}, {title: 'title 2', description: '<i>text</i>'}]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    markdownToHtml(description) {
      return marked(description);
    },
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="til-list">
    <div v-for="(til, index) in tils" :key="index">
      <div class="til">
        <h3>{{ til.title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ til.description }}</p>
        <div v-html="markdownToHtml(til.description)"></div>
        <!--<span v-for="tag in til.tags" :key="tag"> #{{ tag }} </span>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

may try the following simple parser in pure javascript.
document and details can be found at https://github.com/casualwriter/powerpage-md-document

````
//=== simple markdown parser
function simpleMarkdown(mdText) {

  // first, handle syntax for code-block
  mdText = mdText.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n')
  mdText = mdText.replace(/\n~~~ *(.*?)\n([\s\S]*?)\n~~~/g, '<pre><code title="$1">$2</code></pre>' )
  mdText = mdText.replace(/\n``` *(.*?)\n([\s\S]*?)\n```/g, '<pre><code title="$1">$2</code></pre>' )
  
  // split by "pre>", skip for code-block and process normal text
  var mdHTML = ''
  var mdCode = mdText.split( 'pre>')

  for (var i=0; i<mdCode.length; i++) {
    if ( mdCode[i].substr(-2) == '</' ) {
      mdHTML += '<pre>' + mdCode[i] + 'pre>'
    } else {
      mdHTML += mdCode[i].replace(/(.*)<$/, '$1')
        .replace(/^##### (.*?)\s*#*$/gm, '<h5>$1</h5>')
        .replace(/^#### (.*?)\s*#*$/gm, '<h4 id="$1">$1</h4>')
        .replace(/^### (.*?)\s*#*$/gm, '<h3 id="$1">$1</h3>')
        .replace(/^## (.*?)\s*#*$/gm, '<h2 id="$1">$1</h2>')
        .replace(/^# (.*?)\s*#*$/gm, '<h1 id="$1">$1</h1>')    
        .replace(/^-{3,}|^\_{3,}|^\*{3,}/gm, '<hr/>')    
        .replace(/``(.*?)``/gm, '<code>$1</code>' )
        .replace(/`(.*?)`/gm, '<code>$1</code>' )
        .replace(/^\>> (.*$)/gm, '<blockquote><blockquote>$1</blockquote></blockquote>')
        .replace(/^\> (.*$)/gm, '<blockquote>$1</blockquote>')
        .replace(/<\/blockquote\>\n<blockquote\>/g, '\n<br>' )
        .replace(/<\/blockquote\>\n<br\><blockquote\>/g, '\n<br>' )
        .replace(/!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?) "(.*?)"\)/gm, '<img alt="$1" src="$2" $3 />')
        .replace(/!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/gm, '<img alt="$1" src="$2" />')
        .replace(/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?) "(.*?)"\)/gm, '<a href="$2" title="$3">$1</a>')
        .replace(/<http(.*?)\>/gm, '<a href="http$1">http$1</a>')
        .replace(/\[(.*?)\]\(\)/gm, '<a href="$1">$1</a>')
        .replace(/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/gm, '<a href="$2">$1</a>')
        .replace(/^[\*|+|-][ |.](.*)/gm, '<ul><li>$1</li></ul>' ).replace(/<\/ul\>\n<ul\>/g, '\n' )
        .replace(/^\d[ |.](.*)/gm, '<ol><li>$1</li></ol>' ).replace(/<\/ol\>\n<ol\>/g, '\n' )
        .replace(/\*\*\*(.*)\*\*\*/gm, '<b><em>$1</em></b>')
        .replace(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/gm, '<b>$1</b>')
        .replace(/\*([\w \d]*)\*/gm, '<em>$1</em>')
        .replace(/___(.*)___/gm, '<b><em>$1</em></b>')
        .replace(/__(.*)__/gm, '<u>$1</u>')
        .replace(/_([\w \d]*)_/gm, '<em>$1</em>')
        .replace(/~~(.*)~~/gm, '<del>$1</del>')
        .replace(/\^\^(.*)\^\^/gm, '<ins>$1</ins>')
        .replace(/ +\n/g, '\n<br/>')
        .replace(/\n\s*\n/g, '\n<p>\n')
        .replace(/^ {4,10}(.*)/gm, '<pre><code>$1</code></pre>' )
        .replace(/^\t(.*)/gm, '<pre><code>$1</code></pre>' )
        .replace(/<\/code\><\/pre\>\n<pre\><code\>/g, '\n' )
        .replace(/\\([`_\\\*\+\-\.\(\)\[\]\{\}])/gm, '$1' )
    }  
  }
  
  return mdHTML.trim()
}
````